# Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: linux

I try to install postgres:
I wrote this:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list"
    wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
    sudo apt-get update
```

And then this:

```
jonsdirewolf@DESKTOP-GNM7V6T:~$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-common : Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~) but 1.14ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
jonsdirewolf@DESKTOP-GNM7V6T:~$ sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list"wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

I am using windows 10 built-in wsl linux environment

```
jonsdirewolf@DESKTOP-GNM7V6T:~$ uname -a
Linux DESKTOP-GNM7V6T 3.4.0+ #1 PREEMPT Thu Aug 1 17:06:05 CST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list"
```

with

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list"
```

since as you can see from link address, it is for 16.04 xenial (your link contains "xenial")